# Bsoup4 extracting child elements that are not wrapped by a parent element

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

### Context

This post assumes the following context:

- python 2.7
- bsoup4
- scraping content with non-wrapped (adjacent) elements

### Problem

#### Goal

- Trevor wishes to extract page content where the relevant content is not wrapped by a unifying element, but is instead adjacent to header elements.
- Under the example below, Trevor wants a python data structure with four elements, each element containing a 'header' name-value pair and a 'body' name-value pair.

#### Details

The best way to explain is by way of example:

```
<h2>Alpha blurb</h2>

* content here one
* content here two

<h2>Bravo blurb</h2>

* content here one
* content here two
* content here tree
* content here four
* content here fyve
* content here seeks

<h2>Charlie blurb</h2>

* content here four
* content here fyve
* content here seeks

<h2>Delta blurb</h2>

* blah
```

From what Trevor has seen so far, Bsoup uses a strategy for scraping content that consists of finding container elements and iterating over them and drilling into them.

However, in this scenario, Trevor wishes to extract each Header item and its associated content, even though the associated content is not wrapped in a containing element.

The only indication of where one content section begins and another ends is by the placement of the header tags.

### Question

Where in the documentation for bsoup4 can one search, or what terminology can Trevor look for to encapsulate this principle and obtain results for what he is trying to do?

Comment: I'm imagining [Neville's toad](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Trevor) asking this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trevor needs to *go sideways* here and use [`.next_siblings`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-siblings-and-previous-siblings). Example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


page = """
<div>
<h2>Alpha blurb</h2>

* content here one
* content here two

<h2>Bravo blurb</h2>

* content here one
* content here two
* content here tree
* content here four
* content here fyve
* content here seeks

<h2>Charlie blurb</h2>

* content here four
* content here fyve
* content here seeks

<h2>Delta blurb</h2>

* blah
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

for h2 in soup.find_all("h2"):

    print h2.text

    # loop over siblings until h2 is met (or no more siblings left)
    for item in h2.next_siblings:
        if item.name == "h2":
            break

        print item.strip()

    print "----"
```

Prints:

```
Alpha blurb
* content here one
* content here two
----
Bravo blurb
* content here one
* content here two
* content here tree
* content here four
* content here fyve
* content here seeks
----
Charlie blurb
* content here four
* content here fyve
* content here seeks
----
Delta blurb
* blah
----
```